# Generate MATLAB Plot with HH:MM:SSS.FFF Derived from Microseconds and without Date

Tags: matlab, plot, time, type-conversion

Similar conversion HH:MM:SS.FFF and plot questions in MATLABhave been answered, however I have tried all of those solutions and my MATLAB plot is still not plotting the formatted time, HH:MM:SS.FFF data.

I have data in microseconds:

```
time = [2551501274.00000,
2552001200.00000,
2552502202.00000,
2553001184.00000,
2553501334.00000,
2554002022.00000]
```

Then I convert it to HH:MM:SS.FFF as:

```
microconvert = time
dayconvert = microconvert / 86400000000 
time = datestr(dayconvert, 'HH:MM:SS.FFF')
```

I am successful with the HH:MM:SS.FFF format.  Then the next step -- trying to plot my time data -- I get an error, "Invalid first data argument."

```
plot(time)
datetick('x', 'HH:MM:SS.FFF');
```

I used datatick function as many solutions recommended, but it did not work.

How can I generate a plot with my data formatted in HH:MM:SS.FFF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing `plot(time)` you are plotting your `time` vector against its indices i.e. `1:6` in your example. In addition, because you have used `datestr`, your `time` variable is actually a `char` array, not a `double` so you can't plot it:

```
>> whos time
Variables in the current scope:

   Attr Name        Size                     Bytes  Class
   ==== ====        ====                     =====  =====
        time        6x12                        72  char

Total is 72 elements using 72 bytes
```

You need to plot something else against your time vector, and make sure your time vector is of the `double` datatype:

```
plot(dayconvert,rand(size(dayconvert))) % dayconver is a double array
datetick('x','HH:MM:SS.FFF')
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this solution and showing where I went wrong.